# Why these two Spark RDDs generation ways have different data localities?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am running two different ways of RDDs generation in a local machine, the first way is:

```
rdd = sc.range(0, 100).sortBy(lambda x: x, numPartitions=10)
rdd.collect()
```

The second way is:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(100), 10)
rdd.collect()
```

But in my Spark UI, it showed different data locality, and I don't know why. Below is the result from the first way, it shows Locality Level(the 5th column) is ANY
[image]

And the result from the second way shows the Locality Level is Process_Local:
[image]

And I read from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html , Process_Local Level is usually faster than Any Level for processing.

Is this because of sortBy operation will give rise to shuffle then influence the data locality? Can someone give me a clearer explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

In the first snippet you first create a parallelized collection, meaning your driver tells each worker to create some part of the collection. Then, as for sorting each worker node needs access to data on other nodes, data needs to be shuffled around and data locality is lost.

The second code snippet is effectively not even a distributed job.

As Spark uses lazy evaluation, nothing is done until you call to materialize the results, in this case using the collect method. The steps in your second computation are effectively

1. Distribute the object of type list from driver to worker nodes
2. Do nothing on each worker node
3. Collect distributed objects from workers to create object of type list on driver.

Spark is smart enough to realize that there is no reason to distribute the list even though parallelize is called. Since the data resides and the computation is done on the same single node, data locality is obviously preserved.

EDIT:
Some additional info on how Spark does sort.

Spark operates on the underlying MapReduce model (the programming model, not the Hadoop implementation) and sort is implemented as a single map and a reduce. Conceptually, on each node in the map phase, the part of the collection that a particular node operates on is sorted and written to memory. The reducers then pull relevant data from the mappers, merge the results and create iterators.

So, for your example, let's say you have a mapper that wrote numbers 21-34 to memory in sorted order. Let's say the same node has a reducer that is responsible for numbers 31-40. The reducer gets information from driver where the relevant data is. The numbers 31-34 are pulled from the same node and data only has to travel between threads. The other numbers however can be on arbitrary nodes in the cluster and need to be transferred over the network. Once the reducer has pulled all the relevant data from the nodes, the shuffle phase is over. The reducer now merges the results (like in mergesort) and creates an iterator over the sorted part of the collection.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/01/improving-sort-performance-in-apache-spark-its-a-double/

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I still couldn't understand, you mean the second code is not a distributed job, and Spark will not distribute this list. Then what if I add a transformation in second code, and call collect() again. Will transformation will be executed in parallel? From my test, I think the answer is yes, but the data locality is still the worst, and I don't know why.

Comment: In the second code, if after you parallelize the collection you call a simple map for example, the locality will be PROCESS_LOCAL.

Comment: Correction: it will usually be PROCESS_LOCAL since you can't guarantee anything. The locality level in the Spark web UI is the practical data locality level meaning for example if you have simple map such as adding the same number to each element in rdd, if you have an idle executor in the cluster the data might be transfered over the network to the idle executor and the data locality will not be PROCESS_LOCAL in the Spark web UI.

My opinion is that you shouldn't worry too much about what the Spark web UI says regarding locality.